# Meaning of "a while since"?

Tags: meaning

I read the following sentence in a newspaper, but I don't understand what it means.

> It's been a while since Germany had so many good players.

Could someone explain what it means?

Comment: It means that the last time Germany had so many good players was a long time ago.

Comment: That means a While Since means "a long time ago".Is it correct?

Comment: The two words are next to each other but they don't really form a pair.  "It's been a while" means, 'It has been a long time" and "since" means "measured from a point in time in the past until now" so "It's been a while since Germany had good players" means "The time that has elapsed from the time Germany last had so many good players until now is a long time."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"A while" in your title is Ok. But in your example, you're supposed to be using "while" as a Noun. You should type it this way:

It's been A WHILE since Germany had so many good players.

In your example, "a while" means a long time. So your sentence can be rephrased this way:

It's been a while since Germany had so many good players. = Germany hasn't had so many good players in a long time.

Answer (score 3):

You have two different things in there.  "Awhile" and "a while".  They are both used to indicate a period of time, or an amount of time, but they are used slightly differently.

Your sentence does mean that the amount of time was a very long time.  But when used in other ways and in other sentences, "awhile" could actually mean a short period of time.
Such as: 
"Let's stay awhile" - which usually means let's stay for a short time.

Oh and another thing, "awhile" is an adverb, while "a while" is a noun.  You can look it up, but they are two different things.